# Loading files from different partitions

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql, node.js

I've been working on a chat engine with file streaming builded with socket.io and nodejs. Everything is working well, messages, notifications, chat rooms and even the file streaming but let's say that we have a server with only 1TB (250gb HDDx4) and my app is instaled in `C:/`, my friends can upload files in the App directory with nodejs and the path to load that file in chat box is something like `<img src="../.././private/filename.png">` . I don't know if it's the best method to do this but it's working.. Now let's say that we want to switch the partition for uploading in `F:/`, how can I load the file in chat box from there ? I can not put the absolute URL, e.g `<img src="F:/private/filename.png">` because it will search in the client/user computer in `F:/` partition, not in my server in `F:/` partition.. It's someone that can recommand me some methods/solutions for doing this ?

Comment: I am not familar with node, but it certainly seems like there must be some way to configure an alias on the server that does something like map '/drvf/' -> 'F:'.

Answer (score 0):

I found two solutions for this problem.

1. RAID method - can mirroring partitions in a single place.
2. Storage server - using only the static files from given paths without any routes.

`Structure:
C:/private/stack/files
D:/private/over/files
F:/private/flow/files`

```
Server:
app.use(express.static(path.join("C:/private")));
app.use(express.static(path.join("D:/private")));
app.use(express.static(path.join("F:/private")));

Access: http://localhost:2800/stack/files/f53f95f15306b5e9.jpg
Access: http://localhost:2800/over/files/8906b5e9597572839.png
Access: http://localhost:2800/flow/files/177fffa8b35508633.pdf
```